# Configuring Tomcat7 with Apache HTTP Server on Debian

Tags: debian, apache2, tomcat7

I am trying to configure tomcat 7 with Apache HTTP Server but it's not working.

Tomcat is properly running at http://127.0.0.1:8085

```
I have installed `mod_jk`:
aptitude install libapache2-mod-jk
```

**my workers.properties file:**

```
worker.list=worker1
worker.worker1.type=ajp13
worker.worker1.host=localhost
worker.worker1.port=8009
```

jk.conf file in `/etc/apache2/mods-available/jk.conf`:

```
JkWorkersFile   /etc/apache2/workers.properties
JkShmFile   /var/log/apache2/mod_jk.shm
JkLogFile   /var/log/apache2/mod_jk.log
JkLogLevel  info
```

To enable kj, output of `a2enmod jk`:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_ALL = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_TIME = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LANG = "fr_FR.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("fr_FR.UTF-8").
Module jk already enabled
```

Then apache2/site-available/000-default.conf contains a line:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
..
JkMount /tomcat7/* worker1
</VirtualHost>
```

The following has been uncommented in tomcat7/server.xml:

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

After all this, both tomcat7 and apache2 is restarted and

`http://host.com/tomcat7` gives 404 and I was expecting Tomcat7 page

Am I making an error while configuring tomcat7 with apache web server ?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is tricky to setup ajp13_worker. But your config looks right to me.

Well did you already try to open http://host.com/tomcat7/**index.jsf** (or jsp or your_file_name)?
Did you setup a welcome file in your webapp‘s web.xml? Otherwise it doesn‘t work.

./WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml:

```
<web-app (…) >
   (...)
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  (…)
</web-app>
```